# Getting custom type always null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Numbers 
{
    public Numbers()
    {
        NumbersTaken = new  List<int>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Bet { get; set; }
    public List<int> NumbersTaken { get; set; }
}
```

I added info to Db with this code:

```
History history = new History()
{
    TakenNumbers = new List<int>() { 5, 4, 45 },
    TakeDate = DateTime.Now
};

using (var context = new KenoDb())
{
    context.HistoryDbSet.Add(history);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

when i try to get TakenNumbers from Db it shows as null.

what can i do?

Comment: Databases don't support collection columns in the first place.

Comment: How can you map a List<int> to a single column?

Comment: You need to create an entity named TakenNumbers. Then thing is as @Selman22 and SLaks cannot be mapped to a database column and Entity Framework in a lower level works as a table mapper... and relational databases do not support complex objects in their columns! The change would take a you just few minutes! ;)

Comment: small hints for the future: **1.)** if you post database code then the definition for your tables and their columns would help. **2.)** if the problem is with getting things back from the database than it might be helpful to post the code that does so as well